# HTTP server on port 80 creating files as root:root

Tags: permissions

I have a camera streaming server based on this picamera2 example code: [mjpeg_server.py](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/blob/main/examples/mjpeg_server.py) and I added a button to capture a still image and save it.

Now I want this to be on port 80 (which requires me to run the python program with `sudo`), and I want the saved files to have my user and group id, not root:root.

I have tried `os.seteuid` and `os.setegid` but I get an error. It seems that `request.save` does not work with an euid/egid different from the program's uid/gid.

What is the solution? Can I run the program as non-root and somehow get permission for port 80 only at launch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/413807/1151724 However, you'd be better off solving your problems using `seteuid()` instead, since that is far more convenient especially if this is a python script (in which case you can't use the setcap option).

Comment: I already tried `seteuid()` and got an error. Perhaps I could create a separate process just for writing files.

Comment: If you are satisfied with your effort, fine.  IMO though, you have misinterpreted whatever you mean by "got an error", and that is what you should be asking a question about.